A marvellous meaningful Mr. Men maze!
My, my - it's a maze made up of Mr. Men! (The British children's book characters originally created by Roger Hargreaves.)

Images courtesy of mrmen.fandom.com
Make the most of the following clues to uncover the path through the maze from IN to OUT, travelling orthogonally one space at a time. Doing so correctly will enable you to spell out a thematic two-word phrase along the way (significance of clue answers and letter extraction method to be ascertained by the solver):

Punctuation mark, or body part (5)
Wild choral hymn of ancient Greece (9)
Messengers on a diplomatic mission (6)
No such thing as this? (4,5)
Title character of a Beckett play (5)
Domesticated pack animals found in the Andes (6)
Halls for public lectures or discussions (7)
US state, capital Augusta (5)
Ademir de -------, FIFA World Cup Golden Boot winner (7)
Motor protein involved in muscle contraction (6)
Senior pupils authorised to enforce discipline (8)
Produced in advance, often for general sale (5-4)
Speech impediments (10)
Steve Redgrave’s Olympic sport (6)
Hogwarts’ house-assignation event (7)
Organised scheme or method (6)
Flow in a small stream (7)
Lagotto Romagnolo? (7,3)
Beneath (5)
R&B artist behind the hits Burn, OMG, and Yeah! (5)
People who drink excessive amounts of cheap alcohol? (5)

TASK: Solve the clues to find the path through the maze of Mr. Men and reveal the two-word answer phrase.

Love the theme here! +1

The key observation is that each clue

is an anagram of a character's name plus an extra letter.

We can solve the clues with this in mind,

with help of the alphabetization of the clues.


Punctuation mark, or body part (5)


COLON -> COOL + N


Wild choral hymn of ancient Greece (9)


 DITHYRAMB -> BIRTHDAY + M


Messengers on a diplomatic mission (6)


ENVOYS -> NOSEY + V


No such thing as this? (4,5)


FREE LUNCH -> CHEERFUL + N


Title character of a Beckett play (5)


GODOT -> GOOD + T


Domesticated pack animals found in the Andes (6)


LLAMAS -> SMALL + A


Halls for public lectures or discussions (7)


 LYCEUMS -> CLUMSY + E


US state, capital Augusta (5)


MAINE -> MEAN + I


Ademir de -------, FIFA World Cup Golden Boot winner (7)


 MENEZES -> SNEEZE + M


Motor protein involved in muscle contraction (6)


MYOSIN -> NOISY + M


Senior pupils authorised to enforce discipline (8)


PREFECTS -> PERFECT + S


Produced in advance, often for general sale (5-4)


READY-MADE -> DAYDREAM + E


Speech impediments (10)


 RHOTACISMS -> CHRISTMAS + O


Steve Redgrave’s Olympic sport (6)


ROWING -> WRONG + I


Hogwarts’ house-assignation event (7)


SORTING -> STRONG + I


Organised scheme or method (6)


SYSTEM -> MESSY + T


Flow in a small stream (7)


TRICKLE -> TICKLE + R


Lagotto Romagnolo? (7,3)


TRUFFLE DOG -> FORGETFUL + D


Beneath (5)


UNDER -> RUDE + N


R&B artist behind the hits Burn, OMG, and Yeah! (5)


USHER -> RUSH + E


People who drink excessive amounts of cheap alcohol? (5)


WINOS -> SNOW + I

We can now use the clues by

finding each character and associating it with the corresponding extra letter.

In the original diagram:

 

And in text form:

    NOM
           I N
    EDE   A
RET  V I T
M
INIS
    M

Following the path, we get a final answer of

 NOMINATIVE DETERMINISM, which presumably the characters strongly exhibit.

Moreover,

NOMINATIVE DETERMINISM thematically manages to manifest multiple magnificent M's. Marvelous!


Argh beat me too it!

@PDT I must've mustered more momentum ;-)

This is exactly it :) Hope you don't mind, but for completeness I've added my working annotated diagram in to your solution (this way all the character names are listed too, which was previously missing from your answer). Feel free to roll back if you don't like it or think it too interfere-y (I won't be offended). Well done :)

@Stiv That's really helpful, thanks!
